# Inverse image of a $0$-dimensional subscheme under a finite morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes

Let $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ be a finite surjective morphism of complex projective varieties of the same dimension. We may suppose $Y$ is smooth. Let $Z\subset Y$ be a $0$-dimensional closed subscheme and let $Z'=X\times_Y Z$ be the scheme-theoretic inverse image of $Z$ under $f.$ Since $f$ is finite, $Z'\subset X$ is closed of dimension $0.$ If $\mathrm{lt}(Z):=h^0(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)$ is the length of $Z,$ is it true that $\mathrm{lt}(Z)\leq \mathrm{lt}(Z')$?

Comment: Not necessarily. For instance, it could be that $Z' = \varnothing$.

Comment: Sorry, but shouldn't a finite morphism be surjective?

Comment: @MaryMoon - Maybe you should try to prove a similar formula for a finite morphism of affine schemes:  If $f:X:=Spec(B) \rightarrow S:=Spec(A)$ is a finite map and if $V(I) \subseteq S$ is  $0$-dimensional, is $length(A/I) \leq length(B/IB)$? And then generalize.

Comment: A finite morphism does not have to be surjective; for instance a closed embedding is a finite morphism.

Comment: @Sasha, you are right. I was implicitely assuming that $X$ and $Y$ have the same dimension. I'll add this in the post. Thanks

Comment: @hm2020 thank you for the hint. I'll try it.

Comment: @MaryMoon - the length is additive for exact sequences of modules of finite lentgh.

Comment: @MaryMoon: Also: A finite morphism is affine, hence the inverse image of any affine scheme is affine. If $Z$ is contained in an affine open subscheme $U:=Spec(A)$ of $Y$, it follows $f^{-1}(Z):=Z' \subseteq f^{-1}(U)\cong V:=Spec(B)$ with $V \subseteq X$ an affine open subscheme of $X$.

Comment: If you can prove it in the affine case and if you are able to find an affine open subscheme $U$ containing $Z$ the result follows.